# How to process NUL characters in a Flex lexer, given that 0 denotes end-of-file?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

My input file consists of one byte, the NUL character (hex 0).

I have a Flex rule that matches the NUL character and the action returns it:

```
\0               { return(yytext[0]); }
```

Below is my complete Flex file. When I run it, I get no output. I conclude that the lexer is interpreting the value returned from my rule as the end-of-file signal. Yes? If so, how to process NUL symbols in a Flex lexer?

```
%option noyywrap
%% 
\0               { return(yytext[0]); }
%%
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
      yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
      int token = yylex();
      while ( token != 0 ) {
        switch(token) {
           default:
              printf("TOKEN: %c\n", yytext[0]);
          }
        token = yylex();
      } 
      fclose(yyin);
      return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're free to recognise NULs in your input stream as you see fit. But you cannot use 0 as a token number, because when `yylex` returns 0 that will be interpreted as meaning end of input by its caller (typically `yyparse`, but in this case your own `main()` program).

I'm a bit puzzled by your statement:

> I conclude that the lexer is interpreting the value returned from my rule as the end-of-file signal.

The lexer doesn't interpret the value returned from your rule at all. Your rules are part of the `yylex()` function, and when your rule executes `return X`, `X` is returned from `yylex`. There is no inner function which is called.

So it's not `yylex` which is interpreting the value returned from your rule as the end-of-file signal. That interpretation is precisely located at the fifth line of your `main()` function:

```c
    while ( token != 0 ) {
```

Since you're not using a parser generated by bison/yacc, you're actually free to use whatever integer you like as an end-of-file return from `yylex()`. But you need to be aware that the generated `yylex` will return 0 from its default `<<EOF>>` rules; if you want 0 to mean something other than end of file, you'll need to add explicit `<<EOF>>` rules in every start condition which return what you chose to use. It's almost always simpler to stick with the standard 0, which means that you can't use it as a token number.

So in order to handle a NUL as a single-byte token, you'll need to choose some integer other than 0 to represent that token, and thus you cannot use `return yytext[0];` if `yytext[0]` might be a NUL.

```c
%option noyywrap
%{
#define NULL_TOKEN 257
%}
%% 
\0               { return NULL_TOKEN; }
%%
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
      yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
      int token = yylex();
      while ( token != 0 ) {
        switch(token) {
           default:
              printf("TOKEN: %d\n", token);
          }
        token = yylex();
      } 
      fclose(yyin);
      return 0;
}
```